# nbit Bitslice ALU with For/IF Generate in VHDL

Tags: if-statement, for-loop, vhdl, alu

I'm designing a n-bit bitslice ALU with GENERATE and I wrote this code:

```
library IEEE; 
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;


ENTITY ALU IS
  GENERIC (n : integer := 8);
  PORT (A,B : IN std_logic_vector(n-1 DOWNTO 0);
        funct : IN std_logic_vector (2 DOWNTO 0);
        clk,nrst : IN std_logic;
        Z : OUT std_logic_vector (n-1 DOWNTO 0);
        ov,cout : OUT std_logic);
  END ALU;


  ARCHITECTURE bitSlice OF ALU IS
    SIGNAL C : std_logic_vector (0 TO n);
    SIGNAL temp : std_logic_vector (n-1 DOWNTO 0);
  BEGIN
      L1:IF nrst = '1' GENERATE 
      L2:IF funct = "000" GENERATE  Z <= A;
        END GENERATE L2;
      L3:IF funct = "001" GENERATE Z <= B;
        END GENERATE L3;
      L4:IF funct = "010" GENERATE 
        c(0) <= '0';
        cout <= C(n);
        ov <= C(n);
        L5: FOR i IN 0 TO n-1 GENERATE
          Z(i) <= (A(i) XOR B(i) XOR C(i));
          C(i+1) <= (A(i) AND B(i)) OR
                    (A(i) AND C(i)) OR
                    (B(i) AND C(i));
          END GENERATE L5;
        END GENERATE L4;

      L6:IF funct = "011" GENERATE 
        c(0) <= '0';
        cout <= C(n);
        ov <= C(n);
        temp <= std_logic_vector(signed(NOT(b))+1);
        L7: FOR i IN 0 TO n-1 GENERATE
          Z(i) <= (A(i) XOR temp(i) XOR C(i));
          C(i+1) <= (A(i) AND temp(i)) OR
                    (A(i) AND C(i)) OR
                    (B(i) AND C(i));
          END GENERATE L7;
        END GENERATE L6;
      L8:IF funct = "100" GENERATE Z <= A(n-1 DOWNTO 0) & '0';
      END GENERATE L8;
      L9:IF funct = "101" GENERATE Z <= B(n-1 DOWNTO 0) & '0';
      END GENERATE L9;
      L10:IF funct = "110" GENERATE Z <= '0' & a(n DOWNTO 1);
      END GENERATE L10;
      L11:IF funct = "111" GENERATE Z <= '0' & b(n DOWNTO 1);
      END GENERATE L11;
   END GENERATE L1;

END bitSlice;
```

It compiles alright but it doesn't work, although there are a bunch of warnings in generate blocks that says IF statement must be static. I wonder where I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking the tools to generate different hardware according to a port whose input value is unknown till runtime. That won't work!

Making "funct" a generic input will allow you to use the Generates successfully, but the functionality will be fixed at elaborationtime.

Generating ALL the hardware and using "funct" to multiplex between different generated results is probably closer to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Generate is used to choose between different bits of hardware being "made".  Your `funct` is an input, which can therefore change during operation.  There is no way to change the actual hardware you've make at that point.

You need to choose between different sets of results from *all* the hardware based on `funct` - wrap your `if..generate`s in a clocked `process` and change them to `if..then`s - and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the WHEN or SELECT statement instead of GENERATE in this kind of implementation.

Your code has another problem: You are implementing a combinational circuit but you didn't specify the complete LUTs, which will cause the inference of latches. For example, you didn't specify the output values for nrst='0' (among several other signals/cases).